# FFTW3 - Parallelising 1D in place complex fft is slow

Tags: openmp, fftw, icc

So I am working on parallelising 1D FFT. As a first task, I performed the benchmarking of the FFTW3 library on **Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz** which has 16 cores. I just did a basic 1D Complex FFT, with OpenMP as my threading library. I compiled on ICC using the following command:

```
icc -Wall -Werror
-I/.../mkl/include -I/apps/intel/linux/mkl/include/fftw  
fftw3_dft.c   
-L/.../intel/linux/mkl/.../intel64 -lmkl_rt 
-L/.../intel/.../linux/mkl/../compiler/lib/intel64 
-L/apps/intel/.../clinux/mkl/../tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4 
-liomp5 -lm -lpthread -ldl 
 -o fftw3_dft.out
```

I calculated the speedup metric for different problem sizes. I am not able to explain this plot

- **For problem sizes between 2^21 and 2^24, why is there no speedup on using 2 processors?** (Even though there is some speedup for 4,8 and 16 threads)
- **Why is there a sudden increase in speedup when problem size becomes greater than 2^27?**

[image: Speedup vs problem size graph]

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

#include "fftw3.h"
#include "mkl.h"

/* Compute (K*L)%M accurately */
static double moda(int K, int L, int M)
{
    return (double)(((long long)K * L) % M);
}

/* Initialize array x[N] with harmonic H */
static void init(fftw_complex *x, int N, int H)
{
    double TWOPI = 6.2831853071795864769, phase;
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
         phase  = moda(n,H,N) / N;
         x[n][0] = cos( TWOPI * phase ) / N;
        x[n][1] = sin( TWOPI * phase ) / N;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc < 3) {
         printf("Error : give args\n");
        return 0;
     }


int N = atoi(argv[1]);
int p = atoi(argv[2]);

int H =  -N/2;
fftw_plan forward_plan = 0, backward_plan = 0;
fftw_complex *x = 0;
int status = 0;

fftw_init_threads();
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(p);

x  = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);

forward_plan = fftw_plan_dft(1, &N, x, x, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

init(x, N, H);

double start_time = dsecnd();

/*--------------ALG STARTS HERE --------------------------*/
fftw_execute(forward_plan);
/*--------------ALG ENDS HERE --------------------------*/

double end_time = dsecnd();

printf(LI", %d, %lf\n", N, p, end_time - start_time);
fftw_cleanup_threads()
fftw_destroy_plan(forward_plan);
fftw_free(x);

}
```

Comment: Would you have the code for fftw3_dft.c, please?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I added the code

Comment: Cool. Let me see, what can be done. And have you tried FFTW3 in comparison, by any chance?

Comment: OK. I get somewhat better behaviour by adding `-O3 -mavx2`.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I am specifically looking for speed up on 2 cores .

Comment: Totally find the same results as you do. No speedup for factor 2. Most of the times even slower. Can you describe your use case? Does it make things better if you do `fftw_plan_many_dft`

Comment: Actually, there is no use case as such. I was just benchmarking how fast FFTW works parallelly, because my academic project is to parallelise 1D FFT

Comment: I couldn't disagree more with @Vladimir F from below. And I explained why in the off issue discussion. The reason I went and got my fingers on MKL was to see what you were reporting.

Answer (score 2):

I do get a speedup for 2 cores even for n=2^14 and it stays consistently above 1.5 after that. Remember to run the code several times and throw away the first part used for the spin-up. Modern cores need some time to get into full speed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

#include "fftw3.h"
#include "omp.h"

/* Compute (K*L)%M accurately */
static double moda(int K, int L, int M)
{
    return (double)(((long long)K * L) % M);
}

/* Initialize array x[N] with harmonic H */
static void init(fftw_complex *x, int N, int H)
{
    double TWOPI = 6.2831853071795864769, phase;
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
         phase  = moda(n,H,N) / N;
         x[n][0] = cos( TWOPI * phase ) / N;
        x[n][1] = sin( TWOPI * phase ) / N;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc < 2) {
         printf("Error : give args\n");
        return 0;
     }


int max_pow = atoi(argv[1]);
int p = 1;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single
{
  p = omp_get_num_threads();
}
}
printf("%i\n", p);

fftw_plan forward_plan = 0;
fftw_complex *x = 0;

fftw_init_threads();
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(p);

for(int iter=1;iter<=2;iter++){
  //throw away the first round, a couple of seconds is enough
  for(int pw=12;pw<=max_pow;pw++){
    int N = pow(2, pw);
    int H =  -N/2;

    x  = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);

    forward_plan = fftw_plan_dft(1, &N, x, x, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

    init(x, N, H);

    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    /*--------------ALG STARTS HERE --------------------------*/
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){fftw_execute(forward_plan);}
    /*--------------ALG ENDS HERE --------------------------*/

    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("%i %lf\n", pw, (end_time - start_time)/5);
    fftw_destroy_plan(forward_plan);
    fftw_free(x);
  }
}

return 0;
}
```

and

```
> gfortran -fopenmp fftw1d.c -lfftw3 -lfftw3_omp
> OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out 24
```

the results are the same with and without `-O3` as the library is compiled already.

[image]

Tested on quad-core Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Comment: The graph I plotted is also an average of 10 runs. I still am not getting speedup

Comment: @97amarnathk The point was not just in making an average! The CPU needs some time to spin up! You must **throw away** the first runs. As always on StackOverflow, if you have any problem with a code, you should post the exact code, a [mcve] and not just something similar.

Comment: I did post the exact code on the post. Also I notice I am doing a similar thing, but instead I am running my C code using a python script. You, on the other hand, are benchmarking with different problem sizes inside the C code itself. So for the spin up, do I also need to change the C code accordingly or can I use the python script.

Comment: If you keep the CPU cores busy, you can use a Python script. But I am not sure you can guarantee that. But note that I was using the real FFTW3, not MKL. They are NOT the same. MKL just uses the same interface. In the first sentence you claim you are testing FFTW3, but you are actually testing something else.

Comment: I am using the FFTW3 provided inside MKL. I believe Intel states that it uses the FFTW3 as it is.

Comment: @97amarnathk Maybe something changed recently when they ooened MKL but it was not the case. https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-fftw3-interface-to-intel-math-kernel-library https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/558934 MKL has a FFTW3-like wrapper to their own FFT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189203/discussion-between-97amarnathk-and-vladimir-f).